# mysqli function to gather users

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As I described in my old posts, I'm upgrading my "small" project from `MYSQL` into `MYSQLi`. I have successfully upgraded the whole project and I thought everything was working fine, untill I created new user.. The problem is that I can use which username  I want and it will say if the data is not correct but when data is correct and login successfull no mater what username I use it always logins me as username with `ID = 1`.

Here's my code:

Login:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $id = user_id_from_username($username);
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    global $db_connect;

    $result = $db_connect->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    if (false === $result) {
        return false;
    }
    return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? $id : false;
}
```

User ID from USERNAME:

```
function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    global $db_connect;

    $result = $db_connect->query("SELECT(id) FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
    if (false === $result) {
        return false;
    }
    return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Any help would be appriciated, I tried out so many things, and were comparing all my `MYSQLi` with `MYSQL` files and still I can't find any issue of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? $id : false;
```

will always return true, as you are counting the rows with `SELECT COUNT(id)`, so you will always have one result

Second thing, in user_id_from_username:

```
 return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? true : false;
```

you return TRUE and not the user_id. Change it so you return the user id, and not true.

true == 1, so thats why you always end up with userid 1.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply!
So, the changes I must do is to change

`return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? true : false;`

to

`return ($result->num_rows == 1) ? $id : false;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function function user_id_from_username($username) will always return true or false. You're getting user ID 1, because the function returns true = 1.

What did the function look like before you rewrote it to MYSQLi?

Comment: It looked like this: `function user_id_from_username($username){
 $username = sanitize ($username);
 return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT(id) FROM members WHERE username = '$username'"), 0, 'id');
}`